# Evitar que una excepción se eleve al nivel superior en asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Quisiera que cuando el `Catch` capture la excepción pintar un log pero PRINCIPALMENTE, que no se eleve al nivel superior en la pila de llamadas, en otras palabras que se anule la excepción para permanecer en el programa que ha capturado dicha excepción.

Quiero que cuando me capture la excepción "Subproceso anulado", este lo está produciendo una llamada a un USP que demora unos minutos, vuelva a llamar al USP.
Es algo como este seudocódigo:

```
While true
    Try
        llamar al USP
    exit
    Catch ex As Exception
        pintar en un archivo log
        (una vez que llega a ejecutar la ult.línea del Catch, se eleva la excepcion y eso no queremos, queremos que permanezca dentro de este loop para que vuelva a llmar al USP)
    end try
    (Se supone que tiene que llegar a aquí despues de ejecutar las líneas del Catch)
end
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si añades una variable `isFail = False` de tipo `bool` por ejemplo, en el `catch` puedes cambiar su valor a `True` y añades una condición más en el `While` que sea `And isFail = True`, y si ha ido correctamente pones `isFail = False` y con eso debería de seguir ejecutando sin parar hasta que haya ido bien, pero vamos tampoco detallas mucho el funcionamiento del algoritmo por lo que poco más te puedo decir